# Ruby interpreted variables is_a?

Tags: ruby, variable-types

I am looking to check a variabe for its type based on the value held in another variable but am struggling with it. I'm completely new to ruby but can anyone tell me how to have the value of a variable interpreted in the expression? My current code looks like:-

```
if variable.is_a?("#{variable_type}")
    puts variable
end
```

Where `variable` could contain anything and `variable_type` contains the type of a variable like String or Fixnum. But currently this code gives me `TypeError: Class or module required.` Any thoughts?

Comment: If you are using Rails, rather than `Object.const_get(variable_type)` you can just use `variable_type.constantize` to get a class from a String.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code sends a String object to the `#is_a?` method and the `#is_a` method expects a Class.

For example, `String` vs. `"String"`:

```
variable = "Hello!"
variable_type = String
"#{variable_type}" # => "String"

# your code:
if variable.is_a?("#{variable_type}")
    puts variable
end
```

[`#is_a?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Object.html#method-i-is_a-3F) expects the actual Class (String, Fixnum, etc') - as you can see in [the documentation for `#is_a?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Object.html#method-i-is_a-3F).

You can adjust your code in two ways:

1. pass the Class, without the string.
2. convert the string to the class using [`Module.const_get`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Module.html#method-i-const_get).

here is an example:

```
variable = "Hello!"
variable_type = String
"#{variable_type}" # => "String"

# passing the actual class:
if variable.is_a?(variable_type)
    puts variable
end

# or,

# converting the string to a the type:
if variable.is_a?( Module.const_get( variable_type.to_s ) )
    puts variable
end
```

Comment: Generally, it is not recommended to use `"#{var}"` when you can just use `var` or `var.to_s`.

Answer (score 2):

Just a little example:

```
variable = 1

variable_type = String
puts variable if variable.is_a?(variable_type)
#=> nil

variable_type = Integer
puts variable if variable.is_a?(variable_type)
#=> 1
```

Or when your `variable_type` is a string:

```
variable_type = 'Integer'
puts variable if variable.is_a?(Object.const_get(variable_type))
#=> 1
```

Comment: Thanks, you've helped me understand more what my problem is, this makes sense, but what if variable_type = "String" rather than String?

Comment: @JjNo it will return the same error, since it would be a string, not a class name

Comment: To get a class from a string, use `Object.const_get("String")`.

Answer (score 1):

> `TypeError: Class or module required`

It means, that to use `is_a?` `varibale_type` should hold a class name (any).

Therefore if you hold anything else except for class name in `variable_type` it will give you this error.

```
a = :a

variable_type = Symbol
a if a.is_a? variable_type
# => :a
```

If variable type is a string, you will have to use [`Module#const_get`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/const_get):

```
variable_type = 'Symbol'
a if a.is_a? Object.const_get(variable_type)
# => :a
```

Comment: Thanks. So I guess my next question would be assuming that I do have a string in `variable_type` how can I convert this to a class name?